# Insert timestamp to XML file from HTML form

Tags: php, xml, timestamp

I need to add a timestamp to an XML file when submission from a HTML form is submitted. I have a php script that creates an XML file with data generated from the form. When the form is submitted I want it to had a timestamp element to the XML file. What would be the easiest what to do this? Hidden field in the form or is there something I can add to the php script that will do this for me?

Here is the script I use that creates the file and inserts the data from the form into the XML file.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
    {
        header('Location: http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxmesqLSR.php');
    }

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$report = $_POST['report'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

$fname = htmlentities($fname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$lname = htmlentities($lname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$location = htmlentities($location, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$report = htmlentities($report, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$description = htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

$xml->reports = "";
$xml->reports->addChild('fname', $fname);
$xml->reports->addChild('lname', $lname);
$xml->reports->addChild('location', $location);
$xml->reports->addChild('report', $report);
$xml->reports->addChild('description', $description);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('test2.xml');

?>
```

-Thanks!

Comment: How about [`date()`](http://php.net/date) ?

Comment: you can try `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());`

Comment: Well that's for formatting it but, would that go in the php script or the HTML form? I want this to be hidden and timestamp each XML entry upon submission of the form.

Comment: As suggested above, adding something like `$xml->reports->addChild('timestamp', date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()));` (maybe as the first entry in the XML file) should add the info you're after. It will generate the time stamp when the script is run, and you don't need to add anything to the html form.

Comment: $xml->reports->addChild('timestamp', date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time())); that works great. I was trying to use it as value from a hidden field.

Comment: so substract it from time()? `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()-60*60)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create another input field in html if data is not put by user. You can add child to your xml file.

add this line

```
$xml->reports->addChild('time', date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()-60*60));
```

this will add date which is one hour back as you suggested in comments. You can change date format to fit your needs. To find how to do it you can check [Date() in manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)